# How do I compile and run a C program in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: compiler-construction, build, compilation, sublimetext2

I am completely new to programming. I have no idea how to compile & run a simple C program in Sublime Text 2.

(In college I was asked to use Turbo C++ 3.0 but I found that IDE quite ancient.)

I'm using Windows 8 (x64). Here's the error I got when I clicked on build.

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the compile command, it's doubtful anyone can help. You would be better off starting your programming compile attempts on the command line so your clear on the compile process. There are endless examples on google for you to follow.

Comment: Anything I said helpful at all?

Comment: C or C++? Sublime has built-in C++ build options, and given the compiler output starting with "g++" it looks like you're compiling C++ but your description said C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I realize you mentioned that you're new to programming but [this page](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) might still help you to figure out what's going on.  Basically, it looks as if you're not specifying the name of the C file to compile in the build command correctly. In the example given at that webpage, the file to be compiled is specified by the `$file` parameter.

---

EDIT: Looking again at the output, try saving your file as a *.c file--`File->Save As` and call it something like *Hello.c*. The .c extension is the important thing in this case.

---

EDIT 2: You don't need two `;` at the end of line 4. That's unlikely to be your problem (should compile ok) but it's not needed and you shouldn't get into the habit.

Comment: Thank you, after saving it, I built it and it was a success.

Comment: Glad to hear it--best of luck with your learning in the future.

Answer (score 37):

I recommend you to read [build document](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) of Sublime Text 2.

Here is the answer. In Sublime, click Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...

For Windows user, type the following code and save:

```js
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell" : true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

For Mac user, type the following code:

```js
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc",  "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file_name"],
    "cmd" : ["./$file_base_name"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell" : false,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

For Linux User, copy the following code

```js
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && ./${file_base_name}"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

Comment: I was also facing the same problem, I made the new build system but now how should I compile and run my code from sublime text .

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal Goto **tools** > **Change bulid system** and select your build system.

Comment: trailing comma in fourth line in example for Linux user

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the C++ compiler,

I use mingw. Once that is installed the c:/mingw and you have added it to the computers environment path it should start compiling.

I use this version of mingw as it includes Boost.
http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

Answer (score 3):

You didn't saved the file.
The compiler can't find the file.

Save the file and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
{
    "shell": false,
    "cmd": [
        "sh", "-c", "clang $file_path/$file_name && $file_path/a.out && rm $file_path/a.out"
    ],
    "encoding": "cp1252"
}
```

It solves the compile and run problem (st2 doesn't allow to run multiple cmd for build)