# Running Hello World on Sublime Text 3

Tags: c, macos, sublimetext3

So to set up compiling on sublime text3 on mac , I've downloaded the developer xcode tools and then

I made a new build system and saved it as 'c' :

```
{
"cmd" : ["gcc",  "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file_name"],
"cmd" : ["./$file_base_name"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell" : false,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

After this my program is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
printf("Hello World");
return 0;
}
```

And when I tried 'building' it I get this error

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Hello World'
[cmd: ['./Hello World']]
[dir: /Users/(username)/Desktop/Programming/Random C Programs]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

What is wrong?

I have also saved my Hello World files on my desktop named specifically "Hello World.c" if that makes any difference

---

New Error referring to schwern's comment:

Now I am getting this:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: './HelloWorld'
[cmd: ['./HelloWorld']]
[dir: /Users/(username)/Desktop/Programming/RandomCPrograms]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

Comment: Are you sure that the first `cmd` is getting executed? Is it allowed to specify several `cmd`s in a single "build system" in Sublime at all?

Comment: First programming rule of thumb; spaces in filenames are asking for a bad time. Just don't do it. :)

Comment: According to your configuration, it should be compiling `source.c` and thus outputting `./source` as the executable. But it's showing that it's trying to run `./HelloWorld`. Which is it?

Comment: @Qix Thanks, will do it in the future :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile and run C in sublime text 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225343/how-to-compile-and-run-c-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: You should probably avoid the whitespace in the filename. Unix and Linux are decades behind Windows with respect to long file names. Windows needs "extra care", while Unix and Linux sometimes require "extraordinary effort".

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The problem is likely that you have a space in the file name and didn't escape it or quote the filename.</strike>

`./Hello World` is running the program `./Hello` with the first argument being `World`.

(That was wrong, Sublime doesn't run `cmd` through the shell so spaces are fine)

You can't have two entries with the same key, the second `cmd` has overwritten the first. I'm not sure how you'd run two commands. See [Build Systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) for more.

Comment: Good catch on the JSON bit. That's most likely your problem; your second command is overwriting the first one, so it's going to try to run without actually compiling it.

Comment: @Qix sorry guys but all of this isn't making a lot of sense since I got a new laptop and wanted to start learning programming by using sublime text and compiling on it. I'm learning C atm and just wanted to run a basic c program to test sublime text out on how it runs programs. Would any of you be able to tell me exactly what to change to fix all of this and run my code?

Comment: @dydxx I'd suggest not using your editor to compile C code. [Write a `Makefile`](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/). You're gonna have to learn how to do that, might as well do it now. Learn C The Hard Way walks you through it. Anyhow, I listed an existing question with your answer in the question comments.