# how to add gtk in sublime text 3 to create graphical user interface for c programs

Tags: c, sublimetext3, gtk3

I'm learning c programming language. Almost I completed all the syntaxes and example programs. I want to create **graphical user interface** for the source code written in C. A lot of browsing in google I found that it is possible with **gtk+**. Now I'm using **Sublime Text 3** to write and compile my C programs. Is there any way to add **gtk+** with the **sublimt text**.

Comment: sublime text is a text editor not an IDE

Comment: @dparoli You can still get sublime to launch the compiler though by either using Make or sublime's format.

Comment: my fault, I didnt know of sublime format

Answer (score 1):

it's Been a **while**.

For those who stumble upon this..

Try the following:

1. click 'Tools' tab > 'Build System' > 'New Build System...'
2. in the file add the following:

```
{
  "shell_cmd":"gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o $file_base_name $file `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`",
"selector":"source.c",
"working_dir":"$file_path"
}
```

3. save file with reasonable name. keeping in mind that this compiles for gtk3.0.

Note: this only compiles the current active single file.

Note 2: only tested in ST3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Make` if you have it installed on your system. Or if it's just a single .c file, you can quickly use the command line. See this questions on how to compile and run [C programs from within sublime text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225343/how-to-compile-and-run-c-in-sublime-text-3).

To get the CFLAGS and linking flags use:

```
pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs
```

As you have not stated the OS you are using I am going to assume Linux, or some Unix.

then:

```
gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -g $(pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs) gtk.c -o gtk
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My os is windows 7. I'm just a beginner. I can't understand anything in the reply you have given. Can you please guide me with a step by step procedure.:-)