# Run C Program in Sublime Text 3 on Linux Mint

Tags: c, sublimetext3, linux-mint

I want to run C program like the one below (with input) opened in a  terminal window triggered by sublime-build in Sublime Text 3 on Linux Mint.

What do I write in my sublime-build file to make it happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Your number: %d", n);
}
```

This sublime-build file below:

```
{
"cmd" : ["gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && ./${file_base_name}"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell": true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

This build system fails to open a new terminal window for execution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compile and run C in sublime text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225343/how-to-compile-and-run-c-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: I checked everywhere... didn't get my answer

Comment: Add `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -o ${file_base_name} $file_base_name`, (you are missing the last `$file_base_name`) you also have no compiler warnings enabled -- and do not accept code until it compiles without warning.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `gcc` command line on the terminal:

```
gcc -Wall program.c -o program.exe
```

Then you run your program:

```
./program.exe
```

Comment: I can execute in terminal, but I want to open output in terminal window that's triggered by sublime text