# Sublime Text 2 and C

Tags: c++, c

I'm new to Sublime Text 2 text editor and 
I have these code saved as `.cpp`, using C obviously, but it won't build?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

It displays:

```
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ "C:\Users\KrizMalchael\Desktop\hello.cpp" -o "C:\Users\KrizMalchael\Desktop/hello"]
[dir: C:\Users\KrizMalchael\Desktop]
[path: C:\Program Files\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\]
```

Comment: .cpp is a file extension for C++ -- not C. Also the error means that you don't have g++ in your path.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build a `C` program but you have named your file as a `C++` prgram. Change your file extension to `.c`. Also you may need to do some set up to get sublime text to build programs under windows. There is a question about that here: [How do I compile and run a C program in Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621562/how-do-i-compile-and-run-a-c-program-in-sublime-text-2).