# "Hello, World!" won't print

Tags: c++

Previously, I have been interested in learning C++ so I decided to go for "InfiniteSkills" training video (http://www.infiniteskills.com/training/learning-c-plus-plus.html)
The instructor start by teaching "Hello World" as a basic as always.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

but after I build it using CodeBlocks it won't compile
I have also tried using Sublime text too, but the result seems to be the same
Any suggestion?

Image:

[image]

Comment: Is there an error message? What do you actually do to compile, and what happens?

Comment: Add a newline so the buffer can flush

Comment: @leppie That shouldn't be a problem; stdio buffers are flushed on program exit implicitly.

Comment: Is there an error or you are unable to see the output?

Comment: @Useless The result from Sublime text is "[Finished in 0.4s]" without hello world printed

Comment: @FUZxxl It may not be the stdio buffer but Sublime buffering until new lines...

Comment: It compiles and works both with g++ and clang. Try to run it your self from the shell (cmd, bash, or whatever you have).

Comment: Your code working perfect in this emulator http://cpp.sh/9gwd try std::cout

Comment: Thank you everyone :) I end up using Xcode and its work!

Comment: @kybookie *How* did you *run* (i.e. not compile) the program?

Comment: I think that the real issue was not building and running but only running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the real solution for this problem. But my guess is because of the complier. I have test with CodeBlocks and Sublime Text 3 on mac both won't print "Hello World" for me. So I decided to test with another which is "Xcode" and it works! I don't know what the real problem is but if anyone have any problem like me you may want to try using another complier :)

Thank you everyone for your suggestion and happy coding!!!!

[image]

Comment: Check the compiler settings of CodeBlocks and SublimeText and let us know so that the actual problem can be solved without evading it :)  CodeBlock :http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/codeblocks/   SublimeText: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621562/how-do-i-compile-and-run-a-c-program-in-sublime-text-2 . Do revert back.

Comment: The IDE (i.e CodeBlocks, Sublime, XCode) is not a compiler, it's just a text editor with extra functionality. Those IDEs use Clang or GCC-G++ as compilers.

Answer (score 1):

you should add a newline character to the end of the line you want to print. Probably you are not seeing your output because it is still in the buffer. As @Quirliom noted: It may not be the stdio buffer but Sublime buffering until new lines...

```
cout << "Hello, World!\n";
```

or

```
cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
```

Comment: You may want to justify this answer due to the fact that as @FUZxxl says, stdio buffers are implicitly flushed on exit.

Comment: I included your comment that indeed it might be because it is a different buffer...

Comment: @ChrisMaes Please note that `endl` not only adds a newline character, but also flushes the buffer immediately. This can slow you programs. Hint: by default write `'\n'` for newline characters, and `endl` only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, you are unable to see the output. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    cin.get(); // This waits for you to input something and allows you to see the input.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you still face a problem, check this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2977/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. I got an error 'use of undeclared identifier 'getch''

Comment: error?? could be because you might have to include the header.

Comment: Try cin.get() and let me know. Will updat ethe answer likewise.

Comment: Hi, it is running but it only display "[Finished in 0.4s]"

Comment: `getch()` is not a standard function. Please do not sugest beginners to use non-standard functions.

Comment: I did mention the same.

Comment: @kybookie; Could you please paste the updated output screenshot.Are you using any ide?

Comment: @thepace I test it with Sublime Text 3 and CodeBlocks which won't work. Finally it works with Xcode. Thank you for all your suggestion :)

Comment: Is the cpp compiler set for CodeBlock. Check this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/codeblocks/

Answer (score 0):

You should both add a newline command in your print function and some sort of pause.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  cout << "Hello World!\n" //calls for a newline
  cin.get(); //pauses until a key is pressed
  return 0;
}
```

Try this and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too but I was able to fix it by reinstalling the C++ plugin for VS Code. I think the iostream wasn't actually there originally.