# How do you use malloc to allocate memory for a structure?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

The goal of my program is to read a file, and output the word with the max appearances, as well as the number of appearances. But I'm having issues with `malloc` and the syntax of it.
This is the structure which `malloc` refers to:

```
struct Word_setup {
    char word[max_length];
    int count;
};
```

This section of my main helped me find out that this was my error:

```
    printf("Pre-Allocation Test");

    struct Word_setup *phrase;

    phrase = (struct Word_setup *) malloc(SIZE);

    if (phrase == NULL)
        {printf("Failure allocating memory"); return 0;}
```

It only seems to print out, `Pre-Allocation Test`, and then freezes. As I said before, I'm unclear how to fix this issue, but I've isolated it.

*Incase you're wondering what `SIZE` is:

`#define SIZE (sizeof(phrase))`

---

**Edit:**

For those curious about compiler version/OS/etc.:
Windows 7 64bit, GCC 4.9.2

If you would like any more information on that just let me know.

Comment: `#define SIZE (sizeof(*phrase))`

Comment: [In C you should not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: It's really worth using `type *ptr = malloc( sizeof(*ptr) );` so that you can't fall in this kind of mistake even if you change `type`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That is odd, because I've tried both ways, and when I try to build the file in sublime, it gives me an error if I do not cast the result

Comment: C++ requires the cast.  With C it is optional (and not needed).  Are you compiling using C++?

Comment: @chux Last night when I asked people about this I figured out that I was using a C++ compiler, but now when I compile i force it into C, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Curious: how did you "force it into C"?

Comment: @chux I guess `-x c`.

Comment: @black that is correct

Comment: IDK why your compiler still seems to be in C++ mode. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14621562/2410359

Comment: @chux I took a look at that, I already have a C build installed in sublime.

Answer (score 5):

```
phrase = (struct Word_setup *) malloc(SIZE);
```

should be

```
phrase =  malloc(sizeof(struct Word_setup));
```

What you have is

```
#define SIZE (sizeof(phrase))
```

will give you size of pointer not size of structure. You can also use a more generic method of allocating memory

```
type *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
```

Comment: Minor style issue: `()` not needed.  Could use `malloc(sizeof *p)`

Comment: If i do this, when I build the program in sublime, it tells me that there was an error converting the void pointer to the struct

Comment: "You can also use a more generic method of allocating memory" you can do pretty much nothing with a `void*` and you have to cast it to something to give it a meaning, hence getting back to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?rq=1).

Comment: @chux But we are bound to using sizeof() is both the ways so I think it should be fine from OP's perspective

Comment: Using `()` is certainly OK.- simply pointing out a possible simplification.

Comment: @black Yes you are right !! wanted to give an idea of this approach.. Just to be generic I used `void` ..  I will replace it by type

Comment: @krazibiosvn This is a perfect code I don't see any C  compiler complaining about this .. How are you compiling?

Comment: @Gopi Honestly I'm not sure why. Its been pissing me off, its not like the program I'm working on is THAT difficult and I've been working on it for 15 hours and counting.... about 10 of those hours have been spent on this stupid error. When I'm compiling, I'm forcing it to compile into C using `-x c`. Are there any IDE's that you would suggest for Windows 7, because I have a love hate relationship with gcc and sublime right now.

Comment: Follow these steps and compile using gcc 1. Write your code in .c file 2. Compile with `cc filename.c -o file` 3. It should compile without any errors .. If it doesn't come back

Comment: @Gopi you forgot the `g` but, that was what I was doing before, yet it still froze every time I would attempt to compile.

Comment: @krazibiosvn What's freezing, the compiler or the code?

Comment: @black The compiler (cmd), it freezes and I need to close the window. It doesn't allow me to type anything when it freezes either.

Comment: @krazibiosvn Strange. Can you post some info about your station (e.g. OS, compiler version, ...)?

Comment: @black From "*It only seems to print out, Pre-Allocation Test, and then freezes*" it is clear that it is not compiler freezing.