# How do I compile with external header file in sublime text in C?

Tags: c, sublimetext3

I use one header named `header.h` in `main.c`. 
The function test is announced in `header.h` and defined in `test.c`.
However, it says words below even though I use build system as C.

```
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "test(int)", referenced from:
  _main in main-a4d82e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[Finished in 0.6s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['bash', '-c', 'g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -O2 \'/Users/hanlock/Documents/CODE/TEST/TEST/main.c\' -o \'/Users/hanlock/Documents/CODE/TEST/TEST/main\' && osascript -e \'tell application "Terminal" to activate do script " cd \\"/Users/hanlock/Documents/CODE/TEST/TEST\\" &&start_ms=$(ruby -e \\"puts (Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i\\")&&clear&&\\"/Users/hanlock/Documents/CODE/TEST/TEST/main\\" &&elapsed_ms=$(($(ruby -e \\"puts (Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i\\") - start_ms))&& read -p \\"Press Enter to exit($elapsed_ms ms).\\"&&exit"\'']]
[dir: /Users/hanlock/Documents/CODE/TEST/TEST]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I've read similar questions about this in C++. However, it seems not working in my case.
So, here comes the problem. How can I use external header file with sublime in language C?

Here is the code:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "./Header.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    test(1);
    return 0;
}
```

header.h

```
#ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h
int test(int);
#endif
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int test(int i){
    printf("%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you include your code and the command you use to compile it?

Comment: Sure. It's edited. BTW, it works in Xcode with the same codes.

Comment: the names don't seem to match, is the header called head.h or Header.h ?

Comment: oh, that's a mistake when I edit this question. It's not appeared in the code. Just like I said, it works in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

In test.c:

```
#include "header.h"
```

In your shell:

```
gcc -I [dir] test.c
```

This will include any external header named header.h located in dir.
I hope this answers your question.

Comment: sorry, but what's the meaning of "in your shell". what does it mean exactly?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18100051/6523756
In cmd, add "-I" and your directory.

Comment: I tried, but I still can't make it. I tried to paste that code you recommend or change $file_name into test.c or add path to working_dir. They just didn't work. I'm a bit confused about that. Sorry to say that, but I just start to learn to how to use it.

Comment: Ok in QuickFinder, you type iTerm, download and install the corresponding program. Run it. You will be on a shell, which means you give orders to you computer by typing commands. Go to the emplacement of test.c using the command 'cd'. When you have found it, you type 'gcc test.c' (you may need to install gcc). If your header is in the same folder as test.c, it will automatically include it, otherwise you need to type gcc -I [pathtoheader] test.c