# Set Up Compiler for C for Sublime Text 3

Tags: c, macos, sublimetext3

I just started to learn C programming at University. Unfortunately I need a specific compiler in order to meet their requirements.

My C Compiler needs to compile with following settings:
`gcc -Wall -o2`

Can anyone help me by programming a compiler for me, or tell my what to do?

Thank you for you help
Greetings
Alex

Comment: Do you mean configuring the compiler in Sublime Text? Please edit your question to be more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install gcc in cygwin:
http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/

Edit your code in Sublime Text 3 and compile it with gcc

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what OS or hardware you are using but `gcc` can be installed on all Linux systems, and OSX has `clang` which is compatible with gcc, and calling `gcc` on OSX simply invokes `clang` because it's hard linked. If you are on Windows install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com).

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621562/how-do-i-compile-and-run-a-c-program-in-sublime-text-2) on how to compile and link C programs in sublime rather than using a shell.